# Windows 8.1 Command Prompt can't show fonts listed in registry editor

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, fonts, windows-registry, console

I have a Windows 8.1 and I want to change the fonts of command prompt. 
I open the properties window, shown below

```
Raster Fonts
```

However, I can't find what I want. I open the registry editor to 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont]

And here are

```
00  Consolas
0 Lucida Console
```

Why can't I see them in property windows of the command prompt?

Comment: One thing you can try is re-installing the two TrueType fonts by dragging them out of the Fonts folder and back into it.

Comment: I tried, however it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts have to be specifically added to a different part of the registry to be seen by the console.dll (which shows the properties).

Think of it as a UI feature from Windows 2.x they have not got around to 'fixing' yet.

Comment: I'm still laughing.........

Comment: Sorry for my English, but i don't get much information here except MSFT is not caring user experience too much or at all.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/  You have to add fonts into the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont

Answer (score 0):

Standard Windows terminal allows and uses only those fonts which are "Monospace". So, may be your fonts was broken or patched, or you've installed some third-party software which changed standard fonts behavior. Try to undo changes made in your system.

Also you may try to use other terminal emulators like ConEmu or ConsoleZ, they do not have such restrictions.