# Font not in Windows 10 console properties list

Tags: windows-10, fonts, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to customize my WSL lately (Windows 10 Pro N version 1709). However, the font I'm trying to use ([the Windows compatible nerd-fonts version of FiraCode Regular](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/FiraCode)) does not show up in the properties window for WSL, as seen here:
[image]

The font is installed and listed in Control Panel → Appearance and Personalisation → Fonts. I have already tried the solution in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/870390/windows-8-1-command-prompt-cant-show-fonts-listed-in-registry-editor) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/55318/how-to-change-the-cmd-exe-font) to no avail.

How can I use the font I want?

Comment: FiraCode font doesn't support CMD.exe. See this [readme](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#terminal-support) file.

Comment: If you'd like, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: This is not an proper answer. So I just comment it. If there is some tweaking possible I can post it as answer. See this [issue](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/431) for cmd.exe support. Alternatively you may use [wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty) which supports FiraCode font.

Comment: I found out about wsltty too myself and have been transferring over to that. Thank you!